# Passing an int to a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

Can't get the pthread's last parameter to pass through as an actual int. I would like to be able to access the 1 that is put in the last parameter of pthread_create. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define MAX 5
int arr[MAX];

int p0 = 0;
int p1 = 0;
int p2 = 0;
int p3 = 0;
int p4 = 0;

void *process(void *arg);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        if(argc != 7) {
                printf("must be 6 ints");
                return -1;
        }

        int quantum = atoi(argv[1]);

        p0 = atoi(argv[2]);
        p1 = atoi(argv[3]);
        p2 = atoi(argv[4]);
        p3 = atoi(argv[5]);
        p4 = atoi(argv[6]);
```

This below is the pthread I am referring to.

```
        int *pointer0 = malloc(sizeof(*pointer0));
        *pointer0 = p0;
        /* intialize thread 1 */
        pthread_t tid0;
        pthread_attr_t attr0;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr0);
        pthread_create(&tid0, &attr0, process, 1);
        pthread_join(tid0, NULL);


        //if the time remaining of process is not zero, run process[i] again
        return 0;
}

void *process(void *arg) {

        //char **pointer = (char**) arg;
        //int burst = **pointer;
        int burst = 0;
        //int i = atoi(arg);    
        printf("%ls", (int *)arg);
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: void *arg is a pointer, if you want cast it int then you should use (long), although passing a long as a pointer will probably issue a warning.

Comment: Not really sure how I'd go about doing that. Are you saying this can't be done?

Comment: It can be done, Miguel Carvalho wrote a very good explanation of how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the manual pages of `pthread_create()` function, you will notice that you are passing an `int` instead of a `void*` in the last argument.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

To solve this problem, create a variable to store the `int` value and pass it through the `pthread_create()` function using its address. Then, in the `process()` function, cast the argument to an `int`.

```
int main () {
    // (...)
    int arg = 1;
    pthread_create(&tid0, &attr0, process, &arg);
    // (...)
    return 0;
}

void *process (void *arg) {
    int arg = *((int *) arg);
    // (...)
    return NULL;
}
```

Now, notice that the variable `arg` I just declared in the `main()` function will be always available, once the program only exits the `main()` function at the end. If the `pthread_create()` function is called inside another function, it is highly recommended that you allocate the memory dynamically to ensure it is always available even if the function is exited. Do not forget to free the memory before exiting the `process()` function.

```
int foo () {
    // (...)
    int *arg = malloc( sizeof(int) );
    if ( !arg ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: allocating memory");
        return 0;
    }
    *arg = 1;
    pthread_create(&tid0, &attr0, process, arg);
    // (...)
    return 0;
}

void *process (void *arg) {
    int value = *((int *) arg);
    // (...)
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}
```

If you want to pass more variables trough the `pthread_create()` function, declare a `struct` and repeat the same process.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
} person_t;

int foo () {
    // (...)
    person_t *arg = malloc( sizeof(person_t) );
    if ( !arg ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: allocating memory");
        return 0;
    }
    sprintf( arg->name , "Miguel" );
    sprintf( arg->name , "Carvalho" );
    arg->age = 22;
    pthread_create(&tid0, &attr0, process, arg);
    // (...)
    return 0;
}

void *process (void *arg) {
    person_t person = *((person_t *) arg);
    printf( "%s; %s; %d\n", person.name, person.surname, person.age);
    // (...)
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}
```